# vscode Using Typed Definitions in JavaScript Files

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, intellisense, jsdoc

VSCode Version: 1.20.0

First, what I think I know about Visual Studios Code IntelliSense:

1. The presence of a `tsconfig.json`/`jsconfig.json` should indicate to vscode that the directory is a TypeScript/JavaScript project ([docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig)). This means that IntelliSense should be aware of all `.js` and `.ts` files in the directory (respecting the `include` and `exclude` config properties), and all classes/definitions exported by those files without having to explicitly reference them.
2. In any case, you can make IntelliSense aware of classes/definitions exported by a file by explicitly referencing said file. This can be done via `require()`, `import`, or `/// <reference path="..." />`.
3. You can mix TypeScript and JavaScript files.

Given these preconceptions, I can not get vscode to work as expected. See the simple example project below. The objective is to be able to use the `Person` class definition defined in `test.d.ts` typed definition TypeScript file in the `test.js` JavaScript file. However, IntelliSense complains that it is unaware of the `Person` class:

[image: vscode screenshot]

Note that IntelliSense works with packages that have been `npm install`-ed.

Given assumption #1, simply including the `tsconfig.json` file should be all I need. Even so, I also tried explicitly listing `typings/test.d.ts` and `test.js` in `includes`. I also tried listing `typings` in `compilerOptions.typeRoots`.

Given assumption #2, including a triple-slash reference directive in `test.js` to `./typings/test.d.ts` should work.

There is a lot of outdated information out there because vscode has changed the way it handles configurations, typings, etc. I have read everything I could find but I can't get it to work.

Any ideas? What am I missing here?

---

`tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "lib": ["es6"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "checkJs": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

---

`test.js`

```
/// <reference path="./typings/index.d.ts" />

/** @type {Person} */
const p = {};
```

---

`typings/test.d.ts`

```
export class Person {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}
```

Comment: Change `export class` to `declare class`

Comment: @Alex That worked! But why is it necessary? Looking at other typed definitions I see `export`s but not `declare`s. [Here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/bson/index.d.ts) is an example.

Comment: Well, you can use `export class` and import it where it needed: `import {Person} from "./typings/test";`

Comment: Hmm. What if you are using CommonJS (`require()`)? Can't `require()` a TypeScript file.

Comment: No idea. short comment

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As of the May 2018 (v1.24) release of VSCode, the TypeScript version was updated to 2.9 which includes the ability to `import()` types.

- [VSCode May 2018 (v1.24) release notes](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_24#_typescript-29)
- [TypeScript v2.9 announcement](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2018/05/31/announcing-typescript-2-9/#import-types)

This means we can also use `import()` in JSDocs like so:

```
/** @type {import('./typings/test').Person} */
const p = {};
```

and/or

```
/** @typedef {import('./typings/test').Person} Person */

/** @type {Person} */
const p = {};
```

This also allows us to reference types defined in other JavaScript files even if they are not exported. No `tsconfig.json` or any other configuration file required and no need to use TypeScript files. Full example:

---

`func1.js`

```
/**
 * @typedef MyStruct
 * @property {string} fu
 * @property {number} bar
 */

module.exports = function func1() {
  // ...
}
```

---

`func2.js`

```
/**
 * @param {import('./func1').MyStruct} options 
 */
module.exports = function func2(options) {
  // ...
  // IntelliSense definition for this function:
  // func2(options: MyStruct): void
}
```

---

You can also reference types from node modules:

```
/** @type {import('async').AsyncCargo} */
```

**Note:** I did find a possible bug. If the file you `import()` does not export anything, intellisense breaks.

Comment: Too bad that `import()` breaks jsdoc completely, i.e. no way to parse/compile documentation anymore.

Comment: What do you mean? I just tested the above in latest vscode (1.50.1) and it still works fine.

Comment: I mean jsdoc cannot parse import() namepaths. What works in vscode is irrelevant, because it uses typescrpt `tsc` and not `jsdoc`. I.e. you cannot generate documentation from source.

Comment: Ahhh I see what you mean.